# No Frame.java in play-services-vision library

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I downloaded the latest version of play-services vision library from maven & added to my android project.
But I can't find `com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame` class inside it. I tried finding the suitable library but didn't get succeed.
Please help me.
I downloaded play-services-vision from here :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-vision/20.1.3

Comment: Are you aware that [Google's Mobile Vision SDK has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/vision) in favor of [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/mobile-vision-migration/android)

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame is in the play-services-vision-common library.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-vision-common/19.1.3

Also as Morrison mentioned, Mobile Vision SDK is deprecated and please use ML Kit instead.